# Java program doesn't work like python program and I don't know why

Tags: java, python

I am currently learning java, I know Python just fine, but I can't seem to make my java problem work the same way as my python program. Here is the python program:

```
import random as rand
successes = 0
for x in range (1000):
    stake = 100
    bets = 0
    while stake >0 and stake <200:
        play = rand.randint(0,1)
        bets +=1
        if play == 0:
            stake = stake -1
        else:
            stake = stake + 1
    if stake == 200:
        successes +=1
    print ('stake = ', stake, 'bets made =', bets)
print (successes/1000)
print(bets/1000)
```

when I run it I get something like this:

```
stake =  0 bets made = 19832
stake =  200 bets made = 5240
stake =  200 bets made = 3156
stake =  0 bets made = 10338
stake =  200 bets made = 11198
stake =  0 bets made = 6150
stake =  200 bets made = 10934
stake =  200 bets made = 11368
stake =  0 bets made = 8724
stake =  0 bets made = 17158
stake =  200 bets made = 6158
stake =  200 bets made = 7690
stake =  200 bets made = 2170
stake =  200 bets made = 12268
stake =  0 bets made = 15878
stake =  200 bets made = 16486
stake =  0 bets made = 6396
0.518
6.396
```

Now here is what I did for my java program I was told to use Math.random() and Math.Round() and I think that may be where I'm running into a problem I have no idea where to put Math.Round()

```
public class Gambler {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       double successes = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i <1000;i++){
           double stake = 100;
           double bets = 0;
           while(stake>0 && stake <200){
               bets++;
               if (Math.random()<0.5) stake ++;
               else stake --;
           if (stake==200) successes++;

           System.out.println("stake = "+ stake + " bets made = " + bets);

           }
       System.out.println("average successes = " + successes/1000);
       System.out.println("average bets = " + bets/1000);
       }
    }
    }
```

When I run this one I get this

```
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10290.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10291.0
stake = 198.0 bets made = 10292.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10293.0
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10294.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10295.0
stake = 198.0 bets made = 10296.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10297.0
stake = 198.0 bets made = 10298.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10299.0
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10300.0
stake = 195.0 bets made = 10301.0
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10302.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10303.0
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10304.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10305.0
stake = 196.0 bets made = 10306.0
stake = 197.0 bets made = 10307.0
stake = 198.0 bets made = 10308.0
stake = 199.0 bets made = 10309.0
stake = 200.0 bets made = 10310.0
average successes = 0.512
average bets = 10.31
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! What is your desired output? What is the difference in outcome between the two? Please add a little more clarification to your question.

Comment: in python `if stake == 200:` is outside of the while loop, in java it's inside, similarly your outputs in java are inside the for loop when they are outside it in python

Comment: you basically forgot  the `}` of your `while(stake >0 && stake <200)`. Add one before the `if (stake==200)` and remove the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python if `stake == 200:` is outside of the `while` loop, in java it's inside, similarly your outputs in java are inside the `for` loop when they are outside it in python. I believe this is closer to your python code.

```
public class Gambler {
    public static void main(String[] args){
       double successes = 0;
       double bets = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i <1000;i++){
           double stake = 100;
           bets = 0; // initialize outside of for loop
           while(stake>0 && stake <200){
               bets++;
               if (Math.random()<0.5) stake ++;
               else stake --;
           }
           if (stake==200) successes++;

           System.out.println("stake = "+ stake + " bets made = " + bets);
       }    
       System.out.println("average successes = " + successes/1000);
       System.out.println("average bets = " + bets/1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that now, thanks I was driving myself crazy trying to figure it out, but do you know why if I use that the line        System.out.println("average bets = " + bets/1000); no longer works? I sort of see it, but I don't quite know how to fix it

Comment: bets is initialized inside the for loop and you are trying to access it outside of scope

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Gambler {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double successes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <1000;i++){
            double stake = 100;
            double bets = 0;
            double  play = Math.random();
            while(stake>0 && stake <200){
                bets++;
                if (play == 0) stake --;
                else stake ++;
            }
            if (stake==200) successes++;
            System.out.println("stake = "+ stake + " bets made = " + bets);
        }
        System.out.println("average successes = " + successes/1000);
        System.out.println("average bets = " + bets/1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run above Program. It seems fine for you.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged. I'd suggest fixing your formatting as well as adding an explanation of what changed (it may not be immediately obvious, and even if the changes are clear, why they were needed may not be).

Comment: `Math.random` returns a double between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). `play == 0` will almost always be false. The version in the question, `Math.random() < 0.5`, will be about 50-50.